# Making changes to existing page - how do I make a draft page first?

Tags: entries, saveentry, editor, draft, preview

I'm making extensive updates to our homepage. Before I dig in, I want to confirm the steps to create a draft without overwriting the existing page.

1. Select the entry that requires changes
2. Select "Save a Draft"
3. Make applicable changes
4. When done, click on "Current" from version drop down
5. When new content approved, choose the new draft in the drop down and click "Update Entry"

Am I missing something? Is there something I should do differently?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After Step 3, you can hit Ctrl+S (windows) or Cmd+S (macOS). That will just save that update to the entry as a new draft.

Though Craft 3 brings autosaving, I'd still recommend you to use these shortcuts to save the draft.

When that particular draft gets approved, go back to that draft and hit on the big red **Save** button at the top-right corner. You should see another *Save as a Draft* grey button before that bit save button.

Current button drop-down shows the document's version history - as in who worked on that particular entry along with the timestamp.